# filter not working on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I have an array of contacts, 
my objects looks like:

```
{"active":false,"lastName":"fdg","name":"riman","table":3}....
```

I can see all items but the filter just not working, my template is :

```
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-subheader item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="searchText =''">
        Cancel
    </button>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <ul class="list  item-icon-right">
        <li class="item row" ng-repeat="(tel, contact) in contacts | filter:searchText">
```

**update:**

my code is for firebase:

```
   $scope.contacts = {};
        $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
        $scope.data.$loaded()
            .then(function () {
                $scope.contacts = $scope.data.contacts;
            })
```

Comment: Any errors on console?

Comment: I don't see property `tel` and `contact` in your object. You have properties with these names, right?

Comment: tel is key prop id. it isnt in the contact object. its key for the object for firebase

Comment: no errors on console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this plunkr if it helps

[Plunkr for filter](https://plnkr.co/edit/BppGQQ?p=preview)
I have added something like:
`<li class="item row" ng-repeat="(tel, contact) in contacts | filter:searchText">
          {{contact.lastName}}
        </li>`

Comment: when I put your code is working, but when I am trying to get my data from firebase it isnt working. see main post update

Comment: Not 100% sure but I see that initialization of $scope.contacts is to an object instead of an array. Do you think this will make any difference?

Comment: nop.same issue its not related. i think maybe because the data gets from firebase...

Answer (score 0):

if you are filter for object you need specify property

```
 <li class="item row" ng-repeat="(tel, contact) in contacts | filter: {name: searchText}">
```

and you can add more fields for filter

```
ng-repeat="(tel, contact) in contacts | filter: {name: searchText, lastName:  searchText}"
```

Comment: nop. it isnt working you dont need to specify property. you can see that angular example

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the searchText variable in an object:

```
$scope.search = {text: ""};
```

Then reference that instead. Primitives don't propagate along the scope.

Comment: I tryed to do search like this  ng-model="data.searchText" but it isnt working

Comment: did you also change the filter and clear button to use `data.searchText`? Could you post a plunkr of some code so I can get a better look?

Comment: yes the clean button is working and clean the text. but the filter not. filter: data.searchText

Answer (score 0):

fix the issue. ng repeat will work but ng filter cant filter object that have an array, it should be an array of objects.